# Trying to understand why attempting to get recommendations on software products is off-topic

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic, flagging

I have a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/313573/recommended-time-attendance-time-clock-systems.  It was closed and marked as off topic, but isn't the point of this Q&A to discuss possible solutions to software systems for problem's we are having.  Obviously it is a business problem and not an iPod/iPhone issue, regardless I still feel it falls within scope of being able to ask the community on recommendations, even to hear what others are using to satisfy time and attendance systems.  There is a BIG difference between asking for feedback and recommendations on systems and actually shopping for those systems.

But who knows maybe everyone here thinks I'm crazy!

Comment: The point is to teach you how to figure out what a good solution would be, not to discuss the pros and cons at length

Comment: No offense but I've been architecting solutions for businesses for many years now so finding workable solutions is the easy part for me.  What I want is reviews or suggestions on systems to look at.  Sort of like reading Amazon reviews before buying something.  If its a matter of editing the question to re-word it that's fine but the question should not have been closed.  I modified it to answer the questions being asked by other users.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not for Amazon reviews

Comment: The ultimate problem with these question is there is never a right answer, just a forever growing list of "suggestions". Historically, these questions rapidly become noisy and outdated, and the "no right answer" bit really doesn't fit the site's mechanics all that well. And since no one's linked to it yet, have a look at the most recent [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) discussing the subject.

Comment: Fine, I'll make sure to flag all of the other posts across the StackExchange network that all do this from now on then. I really do see an opportunity for StackExchange to create a site for this, maybe not in the Q&A format but there is a demand I would bet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Brent, check out this blog post:

[Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

It explains why we've discovered that "which X should I buy" questions never work very well in our sites, so we consider them off topic. DMA768768973659237598327 summarized it well, "Historically, these questions rapidly become noisy and outdated, and the 'no right answer' bit really doesn't fit the site's mechanics all that well"

Comment: +1 for spelling my name correctly ;P

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a business opportunity then, after all there are not a whole lot of business product review sites out there. Spiceworks is one but its geared towards admins.

Comment: It is a great business opportunity, monumentally hard to do well. Many have tried and failed...

Answer (score 12):

Asking for recommendations on products and/or services that handle the product with explicit calls for reviews and experiences is off topic. It's the same thing as a shopping question but without the overt qualifier of the dollar sign.

The Q&A model isn't for discussion or for fielding reviews or experiences from other users. The object might be on topic, but the angle is key.

Recommendation and [shopping questions age away into obsolescence](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and devolve into noise and flighty option too quick to be of any lasting value.

To get your particular question on track you'd have to reword it in a way that it would be helpful for others to learn from and not just a case that helps just one single person.

Business problems, certain business business problems, should better be asked on something like [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/).

Comment: OK, well than as moderators isntead of closing the question can you be more proactive in moving the questions to the appropriate question instead of leaving no suggestion or alternatives?

Comment: That would only be in cases where migration makes sense and the question is on topic for the destination. In this case, no to both. @bre

Comment: I think the big issue is that stack exchange sites provide a uniquely useful resource that isn't replicated anywhere else, so when one runs into the need to find a product meeting certain requirements and has researched themselves to a dead end, where else can one turn?

Comment: You can http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com @mic but then they also have stringent criteria

Comment: @random looks interesting, but no corresponding hardwarerecs.stackexhange.com

Comment: An experiment before they even consider splintering another topic like colours through a prism @mic